# Powershell script to obtain count, Size for all the files in an online library by extensions

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script that will go through the online library, get all the files extensions, and output how many each extension and the size. so the output should be:

.pdf 24 100GB 
.docx 13 23GB

So I found the below script but it's not giving the expected outcome, any help?

```
# Variables
$siteUrl = "https://............."
$FileType = "lnk"
$LogFile = "C:\Users\AbanoubGhobrial\Downloads\File Type - $FileType.csv"
 
#Connect to SPO
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -UseWebLogin
 
#Store in variable all the document libraries in the site
$DocLibrary = Get-PnPList | Where-Object { $_.BaseTemplate -eq 101 } 
 
$results = @()

foreach ($DocLib in $DocLibrary) {


#Get list of all items in the document library
$AllItems = Get-PnPListItem -PageSize 1000 -List $DocLib -Fields "ID"
 
#Loop through each files/folders in the document library for folder size = 0
foreach ($Item in $AllItems) {
    if ($Item["FileLeafRef"] -like "*.$FileType") {

        Write-Host "Item:" $Item["FileRef"] -ForegroundColor Yellow
         
        #Creating object to export in .csv file
        $results += [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
          FileName         = $Item.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
        RelativeURL       = $Item.FieldValues.FileRef
        FileSize          = $Item.FieldValues.File_x0020_Size
        TotalFileSize     = $Item.FieldValues.SMTotalSize.LookupId
        }
         
    }#end of IF statement
}
    
$results | Export-Csv -Path $LogFile -NoTypeInformation
```

The current excel file shows like that (refer to pic)

Comment: Please elaborate how the outcome deviates from what you expected, that makes it easier to find an appropriate solution.

Comment: any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: still need help with this